# react-native require cycle how to fix it?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have some modals and I get this error:

```
 WARN  Require cycle: src\components\Modal\index.ts -> src\components\Modal\ModalAddress\ModalAddress.tsx -> src\components\Modal\index.ts

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
 WARN  Require cycle: src\components\Modal\index.ts -> src\components\Modal\ModalShopInfo\ModalShopInfo.tsx -> src\components\ParentReviews\index.ts -> src\components\ParentReviews\ParentReviews.tsx -> src\components\Modal\index.ts
```

Modal folder is like this

```
-Modal
--index.ts
---/ModalAddress
---/ModalShopInfo
```

index.ts

```
export { default as ModalAddress } from './ModalAddress /ModalAddress';
export { default as ModalShopInfo } from './ModalShopInfo/ModalShopInfo';

export * from './ModalAddress/Model';
export * from './ModalShopInfo/Model';
...
```

What I am doing wrong ?